# Division of String

Tags: java, string, split

I want to know how to divide a String and seperate it into two variables, one as char and other as integer
Example:
If "C 365" Is my string then char variable will be 'C' and Integer variable will be 365

Comment: We need more information. What is the exact format of this string? For example: Will it always have only one character and one number? Can the number come first? Will they always be delimited by a space? Is there a limit to the length of the string? In order to split this string correctly, a lot of variables must be considered.

Comment: Yes the format will always be the same, that is the first will be a character, then a space and then an integer value...
In topcoder, after importing the package also it is not accepting the split method and showing error, is there any way to import the package?

Answer (score 0):

The `char` can be extracted with `charAt`. For the `int`, just use substring to take the string from the third character (the first is the `char` and the second is a space), and then parse it:

```
String str = "C 365";
char ch = str.charAt(0);
int i = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(2));
```

Comment: Yes it's format will always be the same, the first will be the character, next after space will be some integer value